# How to fix openinviter for hotmail/live in php

Tags: php, openinviter

How to fix  [openinviter](http://openinviter.com/)  for hotmail/live in php.
it gives error "Login failed. Please check the email and password you have provided and try again later !"
help please.

Answer (score 0):

OpenInviter hasn't kept up with Hotmail/Live/MSN/Outlook.com changes, but CloudSponge has.

Check this out and let me know how you like it:
https://github.com/cloudsponge/cloudsponge-lib-php/

Disclaimer: I work for CloudSponge.